# Apache .htaccess redirect single page to heroku

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Using .htaccess, I'm trying to redirect a single page under a domain that I own to heroku.

I don't want users to see the heroku app url in the browser, so I'm trying this in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^mydomain.com/mypage
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://app-heroku.com [P]
```

This is based on what I've found [here](https://www.creare.co.uk/blog/seo-advice/useful-301-redirect-using-htaccess-seo), the [P] being for proxy. Unfortunately this isn't working though. My knowledge about the Apache rewrite engine is quite limited. Any ideas?

Comment: Apache P flag|Proxy Info:  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html  Why do you want to "hide" the app-heroku.com URI?

Comment: Maybe an iFrame would be better for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Ed-AITpro: you're right: an iFrame is the best solution here. Thanks for bringing it up. I didn't see the forest for the trees :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

domain name is not part of match in `%{THE_REQUEST}`
You need to use an additional RewriteCond to match the domain name

```
RewriteEngine on 
#if host ==domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
#and uri==/mypage
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /mypage
#redirect the request to http://app-heroku.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://app-heroku.com [P]
```